# How to enable keyboard return with emoticons android Editext?

Tags: android, android-edittext, emoticons

Is it possible to enable keyboard emoticons with return button in keyboard. If I enable return emoticons are hidden and vice versa. If yes how can we enable or what are the attributes for `EditText` to enable both.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using

```
    android:imeOptions="actionSend"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
```

and that sort of works ...

on my nexus 5, press and hold the enter key allows access to emoticons.

on my nexus 7, I see an enter key and an emoticon key